# Hide a trigger in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, permissions, triggers, hide

Hello all I am trying to create an in **instead of insert** trigger which has the following syntax

```
create trigger HashPassword on PasswordTBl
instead of insert
as 
begin
  insert into PasswordTBl (PasswordProxy)
    select HashBytes('MD5', '@!'+PasswordProxy) 
    from inserted;
  insert into master.dbo.PasswordTBl1(PasswordProxy) 
    select PasswordProxy from inserted;
end
```

As pretty much clear from the trigger I want to store the hash password in original table and plain text password in backup table which is hidden from all user but the problem is anonymous user can know the secondary table name by checking the trigger.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide me a way to hide or encrypt this trigger or any alternate way to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: not an answer to your question, but _please_ consider not storing the plaintext password at all. If the user loses his password, generate a random one and force him/her to reset on first connection.

Comment: @Mat: that would probably be the wiser choice, indeed !

Comment: @Mat: No, that is the **only** answer to the question. You should never store passwords as plan text. Period.

Comment: I can't express how bad this is succintly. So -1 instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hide a trigger - but you can encrypt its source code, so regular users cannot see what's inside:

```
create trigger HashPassword on PasswordTBl
WITH ENCRYPTION
instead of insert
as 
begin
   ......
```

It's a simple and easy protection - but also quite a weak one; there are ways to decrypt that source code again. It can keep away the sneaky employee, but certainly not a determined hacker....

Comment: Thanks marc for such a quick response, For now it fulfills my requirement and for hacker perspective will think on alternatives later on.

Comment: @Isha: I disgree: fix your permissions so code isn't visible. This doesn't detract from marc_s' answer.

Comment: "regular users" should be able to see the triger definition!

Answer (score 1):

Your users should not be able to read the trigger definition, even if they have rights to INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT. If they can, they have too many rights.

`WITH ENCRYPTION` only obfuscates the code from folk *with* rights already.

See `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION`: [One](http://sql.richarddouglas.co.uk/archive/2010/05/grant-view-definition.html), [Two](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1593) and [Three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173848.aspx). Note, this is implied by ALTER and db_owner rights.

One question: if someone can see the code, they can probably see your backup table... Even if it is in master the user *requires* rights there to write into the table because it is a different database.

If you haven't granted rights to the users or public in master, then this implies sysadmin rights. Which means someone can undo `WITH ENCRYPTION` easily

Lordy, this is wrong on so many levels.